# Sending Python Data to a PHP Script

Tags: python

Right now my Python script is printing data like this:

```
print(address)
```

I basically just wanted to send it to a PHP script in the same directory like this:

```
script.php?data=address
```

This isn't a publicly accessible server, so I don't think sending a curl request won't work.

The data can be sent as a GET or POST request, whichever would be easiest to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer that uses that [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). It is a third party library so you would have to install it `pip install requests`.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("http://localhost/script.php?data=address")
print(resp.text)
```

If you really wanted to, you can use curl. Just use either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` to refer to yourself. The server doesn't have to be publicly accessible, but you do need to be hosting the directory your PHP is in with something like Apache.

If it's not that critical for the data to be sent as a GET or POST request, you can also just call the PHP script directly. `subprocess.run(['php', '/path/to/script', 'arg1', 'arg2'])`, and then in PHP you can access the arguments passed in using the [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) global variable. This method allows you to not have to worry about hosting the PHP code.

Comment: Got this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'` when trying to use your second option.

Comment: Wrong version of Python, changed to running script in 3 and it works :)  Thanks!